# How to dynamically update availability and price of product in Saleor

Tags: saleor

I don't have the inventory myself, I depend on a third party that has a very poor API to get the price and availability of a product. I was planning to check for price and availability on the fly each time a user visits the product page and save these values to my DB. Can saleor has a way to accomplish this dynamic stock and pricing?

Answer (score 3):

Saleor dev here. In theory, you could use the plugin system for that - in Saleor there is a bunch of hooks functions that can be overridden to customize particular parts of the flow. E.g. here is a plugin that anonymizes users' data in checkout that we use in our public demo shop: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/extensions/plugins/anonymize/plugin.py

I think we don't have a hook for the product's price calculation now, but we were thinking that it might be useful for cases like yours.

But I think that fetching prices on the fly is tricky. Wouldn't it be better for you to periodically synchronize with this API to fetch products, prices and availability? That's what I would usually suggest - to build a Django command that does the synchronization and run it periodically.